Install OpenCV dev for ubuntu in Release Mode
I'm working on a project that generates a library C++ that will be shared to other teams.

This library depends on OpenCV

To develop this I'm using a Docker image based on Ubuntu and installing libopencv-dev:
FROM ubuntu:22.04 as base
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt -q update -y && apt -q install -y \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    gdb \
    wget \
    libopencv-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libswscale-dev

Then I use a CMakelists.txt file to deal with the compilation, the lines I use for OpenCV are:
SET(MY_OPENCV_COMPONENTS photo objdetect imgproc features2d core)
find_package(OpenCV COMPONENTS ${MY_OPENCV_COMPONENTS} )

message(STATUS "OpenCV libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")

This works great and generates a file my_lib.so with our functionalities.
The Problem
After sending my_lib.so to other teams they complained about it depending on the debug version of OpenCV and them needing the release version. Which makes sense.
I tested this using:
ldd my_lib.so  | grep open
        libopencv_calib3d.so.4.5d => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so.4.5d (0x000072082f29a000)
        libopencv_features2d.so.4.5d => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so.4.5d (0x000072082f1e4000)
        libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.5d => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.5d (0x000072082f18b000)
        libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5d => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5d (0x000072082ec5e000)
        libopencv_core.so.4.5d => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.4.5d (0x000072082e8ee000)
        libopencv_flann.so.4.5d => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so.4.5d (0x000072082e325000)
        libopenjp2.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so.7 (0x000072082df32000)

Which actually shows the OpenCV libraries in Debug mode.

So, how do I use the Release version?


I tried installing python3-opencv instead, but still got the libs with d denoting debug.
I want to avoid compiling the source code myself to be generic.
I tried to look for compiled binaries for Ubuntu online with no luck.


Which actually shows the OpenCV libraries in Debug mode. What do you mean? I don't see any debug library there.

@3CxEZiVlQ doesn't the d at the end denote that ? i.e. libopencv_core.so.4.5d instead of libopencv_core.so.4.5

No, "d" is not "debug".

@3CxEZiVlQ What does it mean in this context? (I can see in launchpad that they for some reason call 4.5.4 a 4.5d -- what's that about? d as in 4th letter, or d as in DFSG repack? something else?) -- It's a bit confusing, because in Windows you'd have release as opencv_imgcodecs454.lib/dll and  debug as opencv_imgcodecs454d.lib/dll.

It's better to ask the package maintainer. Sometimes it looks like the package versioning in Debian/Ubuntu is random.

Ok, so i get the  'd' doesn't necessarily mean debug. Also I get it's the developers of the Ubuntu packages the ones who decided how to name it. It's a bit annoying as building the source produces libs with a different name. I think we will be forced to use the sma home-built libs in my project

Ivan, what's the actual problem now? Given what we've discovered, you're clearly using release builds. Is it possible that you're colleagues are as confused as we were, and there's really nothing to solve? | BTW, I generally dump the output of cv2::getBuildInformation() into the log, so I can see what exactly is being used. Give that a shot perhaps.

@DanMašek you right we are all using the release versions. I cannot find why the ubuntu package has the suffix "d" at the end. Doesn't seem like a big problem but in order to have all the same naming and same version (other teams are not using the ubuntu package) we decided do build it our selves. It' quite easy as the cmake configuration done by openCV include a "DEB" option

So, as stated in the comments, the 'd' suffix doesn't necessarily mean "debug". I didn't find why the maintainers of the Ubuntu package  set this name, but we found a different approach in out team.
We built the "DEB" package ourselves, which had one interesting advantage: we built only the targets we are interested in, which made the docker image we work with a  bit lighter.
I found few info online on how to do this, so I share it:
FROM ubuntu:22.04 as base

RUN apt -q update -y && apt -q install -y \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    gdb \
    wget \
    ffmpeg \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libswscale-dev

RUN wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/refs/tags/4.5.5.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf 4.5.5.tar.gz
RUN mkdir /build_opencv
RUN cmake -S opencv-4.5.5/ \
            -B /build_opencv \
            -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
            -DOPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
            -DCPACK_GENERATOR="DEB" \
            -DOPENCV_VCSVERSION="4.5.5" \
            -DBUILD_LIST=photo,objdetect,ml,imgproc,highgui,features2d,core,video,videoio
RUN make -C /build_opencv -j8 install
RUN make -C /build_opencv -j8 package

This code will generate the .deb package and store it (inside the container) in /build_opencv
